# why does sass & NPM stop working if I haven't changed anything?

Tags: npm, sass

I'm working on a site when my sass stopped working and NPM won't listen for changes!

> ```
> npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent Error while executing: npm ERR!
> enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git
> npm ERR! enoent npm ERR! enoent npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT npm
> ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
> ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\Symmetry
> Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-12T16_13_40_508Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1- Try deleting `node_modules` directory entirely and run `npm install`.

2- Another solution could be running `npm cache clean`